# In Which scanario's do onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) get triggered?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-lifecycle

the only place where I notice these methods getting a call is when we rotate the screen.
so do guys know of any other scenario where these methods will be triggered?

Comment: It is also called as part of moving an app's UI to the background, to be able to restore that state later in case the process was terminated but the user returns to the app relatively quickly. See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras) and [the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states).

Answer (score 0):

**onSaveInstanceState :**
onSaveInstanceState method gets called before or after onStop() is called. This varies from Android version to version. In the older versions, it used to get before 
`onStop()`
**onRestoreInstanceState :**
This method gets triggered only when something was saved in `onSaveInstanceState` method.
It gets called after `onStart()`
For more reference https://www.journaldev.com/22621/android-onsaveinstancestate-onrestoreinstancestate[1] and https://medium.com/@doyouseeitmyway/save-and-restore-instance-state-made-easy-cf6f175f54b0

*Hope you have your answer :)*

Comment: If my answer satisfied your problem then please upvote it and mark it as correct.